# System.Windows.Input not available to C++/CLI?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, namespaces, c++-cli

I'm working on a WPF app with a ViewModel in C++/CLI, so it can use legacy C code. I'm having trouble exposing the namespace System.Windows.Input to the C++/CLI code and wondering if this is because WPF doesn't really support C++/CLI? Do I really have to insert a C# layer in order to implement something like Josh Smith's [CommandSinkBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/VMCommanding.aspx)?

When I try to add a reference in the C++/CLI project I can only see System.Windows.Presentation and System.Windows.Forms.

Where a C# program can say

```
using System.Windows.Input;
```

I get an error in C++/CLI with

```
using namespace System::Windows::Input;
```

Error   1   error C2039: 'Input' : is not a member of 'System::Windows'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the assembly that Input is in to your references. It's in PresentationCore

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I didn't realise it was in PresentationCore rather than in System.Windows.Presentation!

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the project reference?  I usually notice this in Intellisense first...